# Getting active layers with PS CC JS, failing with no layers selected

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script, photoshop-cs4

I've been working with a function I found on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27255364/getting-selected-layer-or-group-layers-array-using-javascript-photoshop-cs4) that works as far as I can tell by grouping the layers, dumping layer names into an array then ungrouping them.

```
function getSelectedLayers(){
    var idGrp = stringIDToTypeID( "groupLayersEvent" );
    var descGrp = new ActionDescriptor();
    var refGrp = new ActionReference();
    refGrp.putEnumerated(charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " ),charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" ),charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" ));
    descGrp.putReference(charIDToTypeID( "null" ), refGrp );
    executeAction( idGrp, descGrp, DialogModes.ALL );
    var resultLayers=new Array();
    for (var ix=0;ix<app.activeDocument.activeLayer.layers.length;ix++){resultLayers.push(app.activeDocument.activeLayer.layers[ix])}
    var id8 = charIDToTypeID( "slct" );
        var desc5 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var id9 = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
        var ref2 = new ActionReference();
        var id10 = charIDToTypeID( "HstS" );
        var id11 = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
        var id12 = charIDToTypeID( "Prvs" );
        ref2.putEnumerated( id10, id11, id12 );
    desc5.putReference( id9, ref2 );
    executeAction( id8, desc5, DialogModes.NO );
    return resultLayers;
}   
var layers = getSelectedLayers();
```

Unfortunately when no layers are selected and this function is run Photoshop throws the message

> The command “Group Layers” is not currently available.

Is there any way to at least return a null value when this happens without the script stalling? That way I could display a message about needing to select layers when it's null.

**OR** Is there any way to determine that no layers are selected before the function tries to run the grouping function?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I use a function from Stdlib in xtools available here: http://ps-scripts.sourceforge.net/xtools.html. Just check the length of the array returned from Stdlib.getSelectedLayers() before running your code above - or inspect the code from the library to modify it to your own needs.

Reading your question again, I wonder if the above code isn't the getSelectedLayers function from the same library?  If so, have you tried checking for an activeDocument before running it?  I would think if you have any layers selected at least one of them should be active??