# Get layer ID from Photoshop layer

Tags: photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

Not sure if I'm doing this right. I'm trying to locate a layer. I can normally do that by group name & layer name. However that does present problems if there are duplicate names. So instead I'll try and find their unique layer ID.

I think this is correct:

```
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;
var numOfLayers = srcDoc.layers.length;

// main loop
for (var i = numOfLayers -1; i >= 0  ; i--)
{
   var ref = new ActionReference();
   ref.putIndex( charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " ), i);
   var layerDesc = executeActionGet(ref);
   var layerID = layerDesc.getInteger(stringIDToTypeID('layerID'));
   var currentLayer = srcDoc.layers[i].name;
   alert(layerID + " " + currentLayer);
}
```

... Only I expected the ID to be a larger random string, not a int. Firstly, have I got this right? And secondly is there a way to get the layer ID from the activeLayer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs are interegers in PS and they are unique for a document only: they always start at `1` and then new layers and layer operations change ID counter by `+1` so it's normal to have IDs in hundreds after a while.

To get an id of the active layer, change the reference to `target`:

```
var ref = new ActionReference();
ref.putEnumerated(charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), charIDToTypeID('Ordn'), charIDToTypeID('Trgt')); // reference is active layer
var layerDesc = executeActionGet(ref);
var layerID = layerDesc.getInteger(stringIDToTypeID('layerID'));
alert(layerID);
```

P.S. this will work only with one active layer. For multiple layers you'll have you use a function I posted here: [Get selected layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63448143/get-selected-layers)

P.P.S. note that your original code won't work with groups: indices of DOM and indices of AM aren't the same. You need to traverse layers in AM list to get proper indices.

Comment: I'm aware of having to do a recursive loop for groups, but I wanted to keep it simple :)

Comment: Wll, even recursive loop won't give you correct indices: groups take 2 indices in AM (start and end). Just embrace AM, come to the dark side :D

Comment: Sorry for late feedback, I got distracted... I think things may have changed now as I get the error `cITD is not a function` However, you can use `layerID = app.activeDocument.activeLayer.id;`

Comment: @GhoulFool ah sorry, `cTID()` is a `charIDToTypeID()` — a common-ish abbreviations. I think layer ID as a prop of an ArtLayer was added quite recently — at least it wasn't a thing several versions ago

Comment: app.activeDocument.activeLayer.id was added around 2018, I'd not seen it before.